# Opposite of timeNthNdayInMonth

Tags: r, datetime

Trying to find a function which can take a date and tell me which day it is,

e.g. if I input today's date, which is "12/29/2014", it will say "it is the 5th Monday of the month" (but doesn't have to be a string output, it can be 5,1 as output representing 5th Mon). It is kinda the opposite of timeNthNdayInMonth in timeDate library which tells you the date given nth nday.

Comment: `f <- function(date) paste(ceiling(as.numeric(format(date, "%d")) / 7), format(date, "%w"), sep = ",")`?

Comment: First time user of stackOverflow, don't know how to "accept" an answer as you can do in Matlab central, but this is what I wanted. Thanks Luke.

Comment: @lukeA Please consider to post as a solution

Comment: @ogremagi I posted an answer - you can check/accept it, if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function `f()`:

```
f <- function(date) 
  paste(ceiling(as.numeric(format(date, "%d")) / 7), format(date, "%w"), sep = ",")
f(Sys.Date())
```